# Cannot run Ionic 3 android app on some devices

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic3

I developped an app that runs fine on most of Android devices. But unfortunately, I have feedback from several end-users that the app get stuck just after the splashscreen, actually just a white screen appears. All of them have Android version at least 5.1.

I could got the log from adb logcat with one device that cannot run my app:

> MacBook-Pro:app p$ adb logcat chromium:D SystemWebViewClient:D *:S
>   --------- beginning of system
>   --------- beginning of main I/chromium(11486): [INFO:library_loader_hooks.cc(104)] Chromium logging enabled: level =
>   0, default verbosity = 0 I/chromium(11486): [INFO:cpu.cc(186)]
>   [LazyCpuInfoValue] cpufreq=[1300000] W/chromium(11486):
>   [WARNING:resource_bundle.cc(304)] locale_file_path.empty()
>   I/chromium(11486): [INFO:aw_browser_main_parts.cc(65)] Load from apk
>   succesful, fd=34 off=1319084 len=3050 I/chromium(11486):
>   [INFO:aw_browser_main_parts.cc(78)] Loading webviewchromium.pak from,
>   fd:35 off:229484 len:1089551 I/chromium(11486):
>   [INFO:sys_info_android.cc(261)] [GetBoardModel] === [mt6735]
>   I/chromium(11486): [INFO:build_info.cc(90)] [ParseDeviceModel]
>   model=[mt6735] W/chromium(11486):
>   [WARNING:data_reduction_proxy_settings.cc(331)] SPDY proxy OFF at
>   startup W/chromium(11486): [WARNING:password_handler.cc(27)]
>   create-->contents = 0xb7a0c510, delegate = 0xb7a3d950
>   W/chromium(11486): [WARNING:password_handler.cc(35)] attaching to
>   web_contents  I/chromium(11486): [INFO:sys_info_android.cc(230)]
>   [SysInfo::GetCurrentProcessName] [com.alupex] I/chromium(11486):
>   [INFO:mime_util.cc(703)] insert media type: video/3gpp
>   I/chromium(11486): [INFO:mime_util.cc(703)] insert media type:
>   audio/3gpp I/chromium(11486): [INFO:mime_util.cc(703)] insert media
>   type: video/3gpp2 I/chromium(11486): [INFO:mime_util.cc(703)] insert
>   media type: video/avi I/chromium(11486): [INFO:mime_util.cc(703)]
>   insert media type: video/mpeg I/chromium(11486):
>   [INFO:mime_util.cc(703)] insert media type: audio/mpeg
>   I/chromium(11486): [INFO:mime_util.cc(703)] insert media type:
>   video/x-m4v I/chromium(11486): [INFO:mime_util.cc(703)] insert media
>   type: audio/aac I/chromium(11486): [INFO:mime_util.cc(703)] insert
>   media type: audio/aac-adts I/chromium(11486): [INFO:mime_util.cc(703)]
>   insert media type: audio/x-mpeg I/chromium(11486):
>   [INFO:mime_util.cc(703)] insert media type: audio/flac
>   I/chromium(11486): [INFO:mime_util.cc(703)] insert media type:
>   audio/amr I/chromium(11486): [INFO:mime_util.cc(703)] insert media
>   type: audio/amr-wb I/chromium(11486): [INFO:mime_util.cc(703)] insert
>   media type: audio/quicktime I/chromium(11486):
>   [INFO:mime_util.cc(703)] insert media type: audio/vorbis
>   I/chromium(11486): [INFO:mime_util.cc(703)] insert media type:
>   video/quicktime I/chromium(11486): [INFO:mime_util.cc(703)] insert
>   media type: audio/quicktime I/chromium(11486):
>   [INFO:raster_worker_pool.cc(220)] [RasterWorkerCoordinator] enable=[0]
>   I/chromium(11486): [INFO:CONSOLE(175)] "OPEN database: _ionicstorage",
>   source:
>   file:///android_asset/www/plugins/cordova-sqlite-storage/www/SQLitePlugin.js
>   (175) I/chromium(11486): [INFO:CONSOLE(106)] "new transaction is
>   queued, waiting for open operation to finish", source:
>   file:///android_asset/www/plugins/cordova-sqlite-storage/www/SQLitePlugin.js
>   (106) I/chromium(11486): [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "ERROR", source:
>   file:///android_asset/www/build/vendor.js (1) I/chromium(11486):
>   [INFO:CONSOLE(179)] "OPEN database: _ionicstorage - OK", source:
>   file:///android_asset/www/plugins/cordova-sqlite-storage/www/SQLitePlugin.js
>   (179) I/chromium(11486): [INFO:CONSOLE(80)] "DB opened:
>   _ionicstorage", source: file:///android_asset/www/plugins/cordova-sqlite-storage/www/SQLitePlugin.js
>   (80) W/chromium(11486): [WARNING:aw_network_delegate.cc(92)]
>   file:///android_asset/www/assets/fonts/roboto-regular.woff2#-6#1
>   I/chromium(11486): [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Ionic Native: deviceready event
>   fired after 1915 ms", source:
>   file:///android_asset/www/build/vendor.js (1) W/chromium(11486):
>   [WARNING:aw_network_delegate.cc(92)]
>   file:///android_asset/www/assets/fonts/roboto-regular.woff#-6#1
>   W/chromium(11486): [WARNING:aw_network_delegate.cc(92)]
>   file:///android_asset/www/assets/fonts/roboto-regular.ttf#-6#1
>   W/chromium(11486): [WARNING:password_handler.cc(206)]
>   OnPasswordFormsRendered called W/chromium(11486):
>   [WARNING:aw_password_handler_delegate_impl.cc(202)]
>   IsSavePasswordEnabled ret is  W/chromium(11486):
>   [WARNING:password_handler.cc(208)] OnPasswordFormsRendered
>   IsEnabledSavePassword is false

I put below the characteristics of that mobile:
[image]

Do you know what is the problem and how I could solve it ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, after hours of digging, creating a new project for the same APP, I found (at least) 2 issues:

The first one is one line of code `this.headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'})` that I needed to change to `this.headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json');`.

Changing that line made my app working when I just kept some pages in the new project, but did not solve the problem in my original project. So finally, I end up to copy the whole src folder from the original project in the new project and finally my app works on this device.